# Why cannot generic extend a non-generic class in Java?

Tags: java, generics

It looks like a `generic` class in java cannot extend a regular non-generic class. What is the reason for that? Is there any workaround?

I was mistaken. As ColinD pointed out my problem was actually with exceptions. Can anybody explain why generic exceptions are not allowed in Java?

Comment: What makes you think you can't? Do you have some example code that demonstrates? All classes extend `Object` (at some point), which is non-generic.

Comment: You have almost 30 questions without an accepted answer. Perhaps you can review your previous question to see if they can be accepted.

Comment: Michael, I am affraid you are mistaken.

Comment: My only guess is that you're trying to make a generic exception, which isn't allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because exceptions catching require the jvm to know the exact type of exception at runtime (reification) which is not possible in java because all type parameter information is erased by the compiler

Answer (score 6):

```
public class A {
}

public class B<T> extends A {
}
```

Works without any problems.

Answer (score 4):

Java seems to do it :

```
public abstract class AbstractCollection<E>
 extends Object
 implements Collection<E>
```

Do you have some code, so we can see the problem?

Answer (score 1):

**You can! - with certain restrictions.  Exceptions are one of those restrictions.  You can't make them generic.  Erasure removes the exception type information preventing the exception hierarchy from working if you threw generic versions of exceptions.  Too bad :(.**

Consider this:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.set.UnmodifiableSet;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap;

//Can't do this:
//public class MyBeanMap<K, V> extends BeanMap implements Map<K,V>{

//Can do this:
public class MyBeanMap<K, V> extends BeanMap {

//Can't make actual method calls return generic types.
 public V get(V arg0) {//Name clash
    ...
    return (V)retval;
 }
 //Also can't do this:
 @override
 public V get(V arg0) {//Name clash
    return (V)retval;
 }

}
```

I guess you could throw UnsupportedOperation exceptions in overridden methods for the existing interface, and implement your own new generic methods:

public V getGeneric(V){
...
}

but that seems a lot uglier than implementing a facade pattern and just extending the map code, but that is a LOT of intermediate code to create a facade for.